# What is more Canonical javascript, console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have recently started using typescript and reviewing some of my favorite repos, I have seen people use back ticks for template string in `console.log`.  This seems odd to me, but I am pretty inexperienced overall with canonical javascript.  To me, `console.log` already provides the mechanism for formatting by putting in spaces betwixt comments.  Why would you use a template string?  Is the performance better?

Example:

```
// set list of items
function printMyItems(item1, item2) {
    // What I have been doing
    console.log(item1, item2);

    // What I have seen
    console.log(`${item1} ${item2}`);
}

// Also variadic arguments seem to work better with the former approach.
function printMyItems(...args) {
    // What I have been doing
    console.log(...args);

    // Should I do this instead?
    console.log(`${...args}`);
}
```

Thank you for your time and effort reading this post.  I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: What version of javascript is this?

Comment: One is not more "canonical" than the other. The first one logs the variables directly. The second is a way to include expression evaluation in a string by using `${expression}` inside of the back-ticks as a string delimter. You use the one that gets you the output in the format that you like. Older versions of javascript don't support the second method.

Comment: **Maybe** they wanted to typecast these values to string, but that's just a maybe and noone but the original authors can say why they did so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a distinct difference between the 2 implementations when it comes to objects:

```js
var test = {a: 1};
console.log(`${test}`);
test.a = 99;
console.log(`${test}`);

var test2 = {a: 1};
console.log(test2);
test2.a = 99;
console.log(test2);
```

```js
var test1 = {a: 1};
var test2 = {b: 99};
console.log(`${test1}` == `${test2}`)
console.log(test1 == test2)
```

Comment: That is actually a really good point.  I also am now starting to wonder if debugging in the console from logs is not as good with the chrome inspector.

Comment: @Michael We use the Chrome inspector for the majority of our debugging. Once you know what to expect from it, it's completely capable imo.